# LaTeX Demerit When One Line Ends With Comma and the Next Ends with Apostrophe

Tags: line-breaking

I know LaTeX has a demerit when two consecutive lines end in discretionary hyphens (`\doublehyphendemerits`), and I was wondering if there is a way to set a demerit or penalty for ending one line with a comma and the next with an apostrophe or single/double right quotation mark? I think this combination is distracting, but those punctuation marks are good line breaks when they are not in consecutive lines. In case it matters, I am using xelatex.

[image]

Comment: no, basically. You could (with some effort) detect this in lualatex. In pdftex or xelatex you can't really detect it at all.

Comment: Thanks David. Do you mean xelatex and pdftex just don't support this or that it would not be possible to write a package that adds this as a feature?

Comment: they don't support it, you can't tell from tex what characters are at the end of  the line. Of course you can always change things by hand if you see something but detecting it automatically isn't feasible.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle!

Comment: When I find myself distracted by that combination, I increase the leading. Usually 12/15 or 12/16 works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out, @DavidCarlisle has explained that this is not possible, but @Thérèse suggested increasing the leading so that the pair is less distracting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).